# Is it okay to ask a question about clarifying the rules, given that the table accepts a specific interpretation of an ambiguous rule?

Tags: discussion, questions

In a lot of cases, the answers on this site do not make it especially clear which interpretation of a specific rule should be used. Here's a simple example – [these](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106920) [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133071) [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) questions about whether you can fly using a Mage Hand both have competing answers: (1) yes, and (2) no, because you Mage Hand only interacts with objects. While the "yes" answer is more upvoted in each case, the upvote difference is fairly small so I don't consider the answers and votes to form an especially *clear* consensus.

Voting is used to resolve the kinds of discrepancies in this example, but in the absence of a clearly resolved consensus, is there anything wrong with opening a question that goes like this, "At our table, we accept answer 2, and, given that context, what are the rules about picking up a box that contains a creature?"

- Are there guidelines around this kind of conditional question?
- Is there a point at which such a question should *not* be asked because the consensus to the existing questions are too far against the conditional assumption?

To be clear, I'm not asking about questions like this: "Given this home-brew rule at our table that is clearly in conflict with the official rules, how should we interpret the official rules?" (which I assume would be closed as opinion-based?) – I'm asking about questions where it isn't clear whether the home-brew rule is or is not in violation of the existing rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### These should work

I don't have any examples to hand (I'd welcome them in comments), but questions which accept a specific ruling, or which has a specific house rule (up to homebrew subsystem), and ask about a specific rules interaction have worked as long as the rule or ruling is sufficiently clear (and there's a lot of judgement as to what is sufficient).

Comment: [Can an Armorer Artificer wear another set of armor with their Arcane Armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/190914) See my comment. Was gonna write an answer saying the same thing you said.

Comment: Another example: [What truth-detecting magic (excluding Zone of Truth) does a Ring of Mind Shielding protect against?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147302)

Comment: Another example: [Can you use a melee spell attack with the Hunter Ranger's Whirlwind Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153832)

Comment: For clarity, it helps if the house rule is using standard language for the system. In the case of D&D 5e, a feature that says "when you strike an enemy" is ambiguous, but "when you hit a creature with a weapon attack" is not.

Comment: Example: [Is a found steed allowed an independent destination and creature when targeted by Dimension Door?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191220/is-a-found-steed-allowed-an-independent-destination-and-creature-when-targeted-b).  The question references another question, a specific answer, and begins with "Assuming that this is the correct interpretation"...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of such a question:

[How can I bind a draconic spirit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196169/how-can-i-bind-a-draconic-spirit)

This is what I said:

> Whether the combination of summoning/conjuring and binding works isn't the question; the GM has ruled that it does. Likewise, the issue of concentration isn't the question; the GM has ruled in that regard also.

This was pretty useful in not spawning debate on what wasn't in question.